# Using gmtime to print, minutes,hours ,days and weeks for processing a perl script

Tags: perl

I want to print the time that my scripts took to run completely in Perl in minutes, hours, days and weeks using gmtime().
For examples

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 my $start = gmtime();
 # do something
 my $finish=gmtime();
 print "The script last ";
 minutes=, hours=, days=, weeks='
```

Any idea about how to do it?
I could solve it using minutes and hours, but I want also add days and weeks
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does the method you use for minutes/hours not work for days/weeks?

Comment: You know that `gmtime` gives output like `Sun Nov  1 00:49:46 2015`, right? It's going to be a little difficult to subtract one of those from another and get the number of seconds elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `time` instead of `gmtime` and you can do:

```
my $seconds = $finish - $start;
my $minutes = $seconds / 60;
my $hours = $minutes / 60;
my $days = $hours / 24;
my $weeks = $days / 7; 
my $months = $weeks / (52 / 12);
my $years = $months / 12;
```

To get the relative sizes (i.e. 2h2m instead of 2h122m), you have to modulo out the next highest factor. It would look something like this:

```
my $seconds = (my $raw_seconds  = $finish - $start)         % 60; 
my $minutes = (my $raw_minutes  = $raw_seconds / 60)        % 60;
my $hours   = (my $raw_hours    = $raw_minutes / 60)        % 24;
my $days    = (my $raw_days     = $raw_hours   / 24)        % 7;
my $weeks   = (my $raw_weeks    = $raw_days    / 7)         % (52 / 12);
my $months  = (my $raw_months   = $raw_weeks   / (52 / 12)) % 12;
my $years   = int(my $raw_years = $raw_months  / 12);
```

If you're thinking, "That looks repetitive, can we automate it somewhat?"

```
# Given total seconds, return relative seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks,
# months, and years.
sub timeparts {
  my @factors = (1, 60, 60, 24, 7, 52 / 12, 12);

  my @rawparts = $_[0] // 0;
  my @parts;

  for (my $i = 0; $i < @factors; $i++) {
    push @rawparts, $rawparts[-1] / $factors[$i];
    push @parts, defined $factors[$i+1]
      ? $rawparts[-1] % $factors[$i+1]
      : int $rawparts[-1];
  }

  return @parts;
}
```

Fortunately, there are much easier ways to do this. Take a look at Time::Piece, Time::Seconds, and Time::Duration.